# Help inserting Ruby script in HTML

Tags: html, ruby, insert

In my HTML page, I simply have an input box and an output box.

The Ruby script I have simply extracts the value from the input box, calculates and needs to display the output in the output box.

How do I get this done in my HTML code?

Comment: I recommend html tutorial, so you could pick up basics. If you _do_ know html already, then please tell what's the part in this task you've having difficulty with.

Comment: Are you using Ruby on Rails, or just Ruby on its own?

Comment: ...or Sinatra or CGI or Padrino or...

Comment: You'll either need to use some server-side setup with Rails or a simpler server-side library, or switch to Javascript (the easier solution).

Comment: "I'm just using Ruby", then how are you getting the value of the input box? Or, are you trying to spec out code you need written?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using Ruby as your [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) back-end. Here is a [simple overview](http://coolnamehere.com/geekery/ruby/web/cgi.html) of what Ruby with CGI might be. You can also delve into the intro given by the [Pragmatic Programmers here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/web.html). So fo example:

if your HTML contains a form that has the field `someVal`,
then you can access it using Ruby's cgi as:

```
require 'cgi'
cgi = CGI.new
cgi['someVal']  »   ["whatever they sent in someVal"]
```

To make it even more interesting, without using any special frameworks, you can use Ruby's [`eruby`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/web.html#UG) so that you directly embed your Ruby in HTML :-).

Something like:

```
This text is <% a = 100; puts "#{a}% Live!" %>
```

Gives something like:

`This text is 100% Live!`

Try it out, I know you'll love what you learn...